# How to create a list of functions and then use it as callable in another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Here is the scenario. I have a list `self.funlist`

```
self.funlist = [self.data_line_1.setData(self.t,self.x),
                self.data_line_2.setData(self.t,self.x),
                self.data_line_3.setData(self.t,self.x)]
```

and a function `do_it()`

when I execute this function as

```
self.do_it():
   self.funlist[0]
```

it performs no action
while when I execute this function as

```
self.do_it():
    self.data_lin_1.setData(self.t,self.x)
```

then it performs the action

The question is why does the first methods fails?

Comment: Maybe if you put your functions inside variables like myvar = print("hello") mysecondvar = print("test") and then mylistoffunctions = [myvar, mysecondvar] and call mylistoffunctions[0] or [1] it will work ?

Comment: In the first version, you're not actually calling the function, you're just extracting it from `funlist`.  There is no argument list (empty or otherwise), so it's not a function call. If you removed the `(self.t, self.x)` from the second version, they'd both do nothing, right?

Comment: What about using a class implementing these functions and passing an instance of that class as argument?

Comment: Your list does not contain functions (methods, actually), it contains the *result* of calling these functions. ``self.data_line_1.setData(self.t,self.x)`` *calls* ``self.data_line_1.setData`` with the arguments ``self.t`` and ``self.x``.

Comment: @TomKarzes yes, it does nothing when I remove these two

Comment: I pretty much understand it now, that what am I doing wrong. I am going to accept an answer, but before that can anyone suggest what should I do, if I have multiple such variables like self.t1 and self.t2, similarly self.x1 and self.x2. Then applying the method mentioned in answer will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want different variables for each call you can do this:

```
self.funlist = [(self.data_line_1.setData, self.t, self.x),
                (self.data_line_2.setData, self.u, self.y),
                (self.data_line_3.setData, self.w, self.z, self.zz9pluralzalpha)]

def do_it(self, index):
   f, *args = self.funlist[index]
   f(*args)
```

If you call `do_it(0)`, then when the first line executes: `f, *args = self.funlist[0]` you get:

`f = self.data_line_1.setData` and
`args = (self.t, self.x)`

The next line then becomes:

`self.data_line_1.setData(self.t, self.x)`

**Note:**

The `(self.t, self.x)` values will be the ones that existed when `self.funlist` was originally created and not necessarily the values that `self.t, self.x` refer to now.

Comment: I accepted your answer. Can you put a link to docs or a site to understand what  what really is going inside your do_it(self, index). I want to learn it as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think this list should look like this.

```
self.funlist = [self.data_line_1.setData,
                self.data_line_2.setData,
                self.data_line_3.setData]
```

And then you execute it with

```
self.do_it():
   self.funlist[0](self.t, self.x)
```

Comment: That worked, but suppose I have different variable t, and different variable x for every item in the list, then this may not work.